# Ton-Äquivalent zu „Visualisierung“

Tags: single-word-request

Wenn man etwas grafisch simuliert, dann *visualisiert* man es und das Ergebnis ist eine *Visualisierung*. Gibt es einen entsprechenden Begriff für akustische Simulationen? Das Paar *Video / Audio* als Resultat reicht leider nicht aus.

Beispiel: Eine technische Zeichnung in Form eines CAD-Modells kann als Bild oder Animation gerendert = visualisiert werden, aber wenn die Software das Material kennt, kann sie auch berechnen, welche Geräusche das Bauteil bei Bewegung produziert.

Comment: Meinst Du sowas wie Vertonen/Vertonung?

Comment: Ich meine künstlich erschaffene, aber echt wirkende Klangwelten, die einem zeigen wie etwas klingt, das es (noch) gar nicht gibt.

Comment: Moment. Eine *Visualisierung* ist nicht eine grafische __Simulation__, sondern eine grafische __Darstellung__.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   Ich finde schon, dass man das Wort so verwenden kann, wie Crissov es beabsichtigt. Aber er sollte das in der Frage noch deutlich machen.

Comment: Strikte Analogbildung wäre *Auditivierung*, dafür gibt es aber keine nennenswerten Trefferzahlen bei Suchmaschinen.

Comment: @guidot Eben, deswegen wollte ich das nicht nehmen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Visualisierung kann auch Diagramme etc. meinen, aber es kann auch eine Simulation sein.

Answer (score 5):

Basierend auf Deinem Kommentar schlage ich ***Klangsimulation*** vor.
Im folgenden einige Beispiele:

---

[Dieser Zeitungsartikel](http://www.general-anzeiger-bonn.de/region/kreis-neuwied/Spaziergang-zu-den-potenziellen-Standorten-von-Windr%C3%A4dern-article1550411.html) beschreibt die Simulation von Geräuschen einer Windkraftanlage vor der eigentlichen Installation der Anlage:

> Dabei, so die Initiative, sei die Geräuschkulisse der Klangsimulation mit 95 Dezibel im Vergleich zu realen Windkrafträdern der geplanten Größe leise, diese erzeugten auf vollen Touren 105 Dezibel. "Wir wollen Ihnen mit der Klangsimulation lediglich einen Eindruck der zu erwartenden Lärmemissionen vermitteln, da bedarf es nicht der vollen Lautstärke"

---

Der Begriff wird auch in [diesem Posterbeitrag zu einer Fachkonferenz](https://www.thieme-connect.de/products/ejournals/html/10.1055/s-0038-1640338) verwendet:

> Die sog. Direct-Drive-Simulation (DDS) bietet Patienten präoperativ eine Klangsimulation des "Vibrant Soundbridge®-Hörens"

aus "Direct-Drive-Ton- und Sprachaudiometrie – eine Weiterentwicklung der präoperativen Klangsimulation" von B. Hallak, S. Kaulitz, W. Schehata-Dieler, R. Hagen, M. Cebulla; DOI: 10.1055/s-0038-1640338

---

Und [hier](https://www.dj-lab.de/vinylizer-kostenloses-vst-plugin-zur-klang-simulation-von-vinyl/) noch ein kommerzieller Link zu einer Firma, die ein kostenloses Plugin anbietet, "mit dem man den typischen Klang von alten, beschädigten  Vinyl simulieren kann":

> kostenloses VST-Plugin zur Klang-Simulation von Vinyl

---

Weiterhin gibt es eine [Bachelor-Arbeit](http://www.ciando.com/img/books/extract/366853313X_lp.pdf) von David Kowalewski mit dem Titel "Räumliche Lokalisation von Hallsignalen.
Eine Untersuchung zur authentischen
Klangsimulation", bzw. in der Langversion:

> Räumliche Lokalisation von Hallsignalen –
>   Eine Untersuchung zur authentischen Klangsimulation der
>   Veränderung des Abstrahlverhaltens einer Schallquelle im Raum,
>   durch die Kombination gerichteter Impulsantworten

Answer (score 5):

Der in der Forschung verwendete Fachbegriff hierfür ist **Sonifizierung** oder **Sonifikation** (direkt vom Englischen *sonification* übernommen).

Der Begriff bezeichnet aber (analog zum genannten Begriff *Visualisierung*) nicht nur die Wiedergabe tatsächlicher Geräusche, sondern insgesamt das Hörbarmachen von Daten. Diese Antwort bezieht sich somit direkt auf die Frage aus dem Fragentitel.

Beispiele finden sich neben der [Wikipedia-Übersicht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonifikation) unter anderem hier:

- [*Sonifizierung von Videoüberwachungsdaten*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/43335377_Sonifizierung_von_Videouberwachungsdaten)
- [*Videosonifikation am Beispiel von Verkehrsflussdaten*](https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/record/2930068)

Wie auch in den Kommentaren angemerkt, wird der Begriff Sonifizierung häufig in Situationen eingesetzt, in denen keine realistischen Klänge nachgebildet werden. Ich sehe dies jedoch nicht als Beleg an, dass Sonifizierung *nur* diese Bedeutung hat, denn das Erzeugen realitätsnaher Klänge (aus Daten, z.B. Daten über Materialeigenschaften) ist freilich nur ein spezieller Fall des allgemeinen Vorgangs, Daten in Klänge zu überführen.

Comment: Das hört sich schonmal gut an - Alles, was mit "audire" zu tun hat, ist nunmal "hören", nicht "Geräusch erzeugen". "Tönen" ist als Stamm hier viel besser geeignet.

Comment: Geht so - bei einer Sonifizierung würde man direkt die Daten einer Grafik "hörbar" machen, aber nicht, wie sich ein gezeichnetes Bauteil bei Bewegung anhört. Die [englische Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonification) hat Hörbeispiele zur Handschriftanalyse.

Comment: _videre_ ist aber auch _sehen_ und nicht _scheinen_ oder so.

Comment: @Takkat: Daten, aber nicht unbedingt die einer Grafik. Ich denke, dass das alles abgedeckt wird. Dass man den Begriff "Sonifizierung" selten im Zusammenhang mit der exakten Simulation echter Klänge findet, liegt mMn vermutlich daran, dass selbige einen eher begrenzten Nutzen hat. An sich ist es bei der Visualisierung nicht anders (eine fotorealistische Darstellung eines Bauteils ist - außerhalb von PR-Zwecken - i.A. weniger relevant als z.B. eine Darstellung, in der die punktuelle Belastung des Bauteils durch (nicht der Realität entsprechende!) Farben auf der Bauteiloberfläche ...

Comment: ... gekennzeichnet wird), aber die Ausgabe komplexer Informationen über den Lautsprecher statt über den Bildschirm ist eben doch noch relativ wenig etabliert, weshalb das Thema wohl vorrangig in Kontexten beim Namen genannt wird, wo "ernsthafte" Anwendungen im Vordergrund stehen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: bei der Frage ging es um eine "technische Zeichnung" als Beispiel.

Comment: @Takkat: "(...) in Form eines CAD-Modells". Ein CAD-Modell ist dabei zunächst mal auch einfach eine Ansammlung an Daten, welche die geometrischen Eigenschaften von Bauteilen beschreiben (und ggf. sogar noch mehr, wie das Material).

Comment: Schon klar, die Sonifizierung macht Daten hörbar, aber sie errechnet nicht das Geräusch, das ein virtuell erzeugtes Bauteil erzeugen würde.

Comment: @Takkat: Was ich meine, ist: Sonifizierung überführt beliebige Daten in eine beliebige akustische Form. Letztere *kann, muss aber nicht* in der Realität vorkommenden Klängen entsprechen. Eben genau analog zur Visualisierung, die realitätsnahe Darstellungen erzeugen kann, aber nicht muss.

Answer (score 3):

Im genannten Kontext könnten folgende Begriffe passen:

- **[Auralisation](https://www.baua.de/DE/Themen/Arbeitsgestaltung-im-Betrieb/Physikalische-Faktoren-und-Arbeitsumgebung/Laerm/Auralisation.html)**: synthetische Hörbarmachung eines Raumes mittels künstlich erzeugter Reflexionen und Verzögerungen.
- **Klangsynthese**: künstliche Erzeugung von Klängen und Schall mittels eines Synthesizers.

In anderem Kontext (Film, Musik, Computerspiele) gibt es noch:

- **Soundeffekt**: künstlich oder natürliche Erzeugung und Wiedergabe eines realistischen oder auch nicht realistischen Schalls.
- **[Atmo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmo)**: Geräuschkulisse eines Films, die eine emotionale Atmosphäre erzeugen soll (z.B. Vogelzwitschern bei Naturaufnahmen).
- **[Klangteppich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Klangteppich)**: natürliche oder künstliche Geräuschkulisse im Hintergrund.
- **Komposition**: Klänge und Töne werden zu einem musikalischen Werk zusammen gefügt.

Comment: Ich glaube _Auralisation_ passt, obwohl ich eher deine Definition von _Atmo_ oder _Klangteppich_ meine – aber auch _Klangsynthese_.

Answer (score 3):

So wie die Frage dann in den Kommentaren noch erläutert wurde<sup>1</sup>, plädiere ich für die vielleicht etwas hölzerne aber inhaltlich gut passende

> Hörbarmachung

Denn was du mit "Visualisierung" meinst, ist ja das Sichtbarmachen von etwas, das es nicht gibt - einer virtuellen Welt etwa, oder von mir aus auch eines neuen Geräts (Maschine, Musikinstrument, Tier, was auch immer). Ähnlich ist dann die Hörbarmachung eben ein akustisches Erzeugnis, das einem vor Ohren führt, wie etwas klingt, das es (noch) nicht gibt.

Etwas mit der Sprache spielend könnte man vielleicht auch von einem

> Akustik-Imitat

sprechen oder von einer

> virtuellen Hör-Erfahrung

oder auch, wenn man schon dabei ist, für Dinge, man erst zu erfinden gedenkt, festzulegen, wie sie klingen sollen (ich denke an Auto-Ingenieure, die sich schon mal Gedanken darüber machen, wie eine Autotür beim Zuschlagen klingen soll; das gibt es ja wirklich):

> Geräuschmodell

oder

> Hörprobe

Sehr reizvoll fände ich übrigens die Aufgabe, für Tiere, die die Gentechnik (oder auch die natürliche Evolution) erst schaffen wid, zu simulieren, wie sie wohl klingen werden. Das Fachgebiet, das sich um diese Fragen kümmert, ist die

> akustische Zoofuturologie

(ein Spezialgebiet der Bioakustik).

---

<sup>1</sup> Du schriebst: "Ich meine künstlich erschaffene, aber echt wirkende Klangwelten, die einem zeigen wie etwas klingt, das es (noch) gar nicht gibt."

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, wie wär's mit *hörbar machen* oder *in Töne umsetzen*? Ein absolutes Gegenstück wäre **Audialisierung* oder vielleicht auch **Auditierung*, aber im Moment müssen die beiden noch ein Sternchen bekommen. Wenn allerdings das, was du machst, schöpferisch und neu genug ist, dass es beeindruckt, könntest du als *producer / creator* ja versuchen, *Audialisierung einzuführen und für dessen Durchsetzung zu sorgen. ;-)

Comment: *Autitierung* ist was ziemlich anderes - Das ist, wenn man ein Audit durchführt.

Comment: _aber im Moment müssen die beiden noch ein Sternchen bekommen_ - Was genau möchtest Du mit diesem Teilsatz ausdrücken? Von wem müssen sie ein Sternchen bekommen und warum? Sorry, ich steh da gerade auf dem Schlauch...

Comment: @marzipanherz Ungrammatische oder nicht hinreichend belegte Begriffe werden in der Linguistik mit einem vorangestellten Sternchen gekennzeichnet.

Comment: @Crissov verstehe, danke!

Answer (score 0):

Deine Frage ist etwas unklar (mir ist z.B. nicht klar, wie man Musik oder ein Geräusch *simulieren* soll - Dar Klang ist entweder da oder nicht da...), in der Musik verwendet man jedoch das Verb *anspielen* um zu verdeutlichen, dass man Noten nicht vollständig spielt, sondern nur verdeutlichen will, um was es musikalisch geht:

> Der Organist spielte das Thema des Chorals an, um uns einen Eindruck zu geben, wie es sich anhören soll.

Answer (score 0):

Eine akustische Simulation wäre z. B., wenn du mit zwei Kokosnuss-Halbschalen Pferdegetrampel imitierst. Eine Simulation hat immer ein Vorbild, das man kennt. Was *du* dagegen meinst, nämlich deinem Kommentar gemäß

> »echt wirkende Klangwelten, die einem zeigen wie etwas klingt, das es
>   (noch) gar nicht gibt«,

ist eine (erdachte und hörbar gemachte)

> akustische Imagination,

was man auch »Audioimagination« nennen könnte oder »Soundimagination«.

*Beispiel*

Du fliegst um einen fremden Planeten und siehst durch dein Fernrohr dir unbekannte Tiere. Bevor du landest, malst du dir schon mal aus, wie die klingen. Und klickst das auch gleich am Bordcomputer zusammen, sodass man es hören kann. Wenn einer aussieht wie ein Elefant, bekommt er einen trompetenartigen Klang; wenn einer aussieht wie eine Biene, bekommt er einen Brummton, und wenn einer aussieht wie ein Fisch, bekommt er eine Sendepause.

Comment: In meinem Fall ist es schon etwas konkreter und realistischer. Es geht um die tages- und jahreszeitliche Geräuschkulisse an einem bestimmten Ort, nachdem gewisse bauliche und landschaftliche Veränderungen in der Nähe vorgenommen worden sein werden.

Comment: @Crissov: Ok, dann willst du die baulichen und landschaftlichen Veränderungen also akustisch vorwegnehmen.